# Python reading json from a url

Tags: python, json

I'm very new to Python, I'm trying to read json data from an API call. The problem is an error saying `TypeError: <http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x030CF310> is not JSON serializable` however the data I'm trying to pull from is the correct format, https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json . Here's the code I'm trying to run.

```
import urllib.request
import json

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json"
req = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
page = json.dumps(req)
print(page)
```

Comment: `urlopen()` returns a response object (what you're calling `req`).  The content of the response is in `req.read()`, not in `req` itself.

Comment: The dupe will give you exactly what you want. If you want to explore other modules in the Python world, check out [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). With that, you can just do: `requests.get(url).json()`

Comment: That answered it, thank you!